# MySQL: JOIN two tables on LIKE

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have a table with a column containing text, and I want to select all of the tables where the text from one of the rows in a second table appears in that row. Here is a pseudo-query:

```
SELECT title FROM recipes AS r 
   JOIN ingredients AS i 
   ON r.ingredients LIKE '%' + i.name + '%';
```

The above query does not work, however. How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't concatenate strings with the `+` operator (it's for arithmetic only). Use `concat('%',i.name,'%')` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT title
FROM recipes r JOIN ingredients i ON r.ingredients LIKE concat('%', i.name, '%')
```

MySQL is weird, and makes you use the `concat` operator to concatenate strings together. Most others use `||`