# Mysql Join two tables on Like with Concat

Tags: mysql, sql, join, concatenation

I want to join two tables on a `like` clause.  My schema is as the link:

[Sql Fiddle 1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dbd7/2/0)

As you can see the result is empty.

But if I use `like` as follows:

[Sql Fiddle 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dbd7/1/0)

As you see I can get the results with `name` or `des` contains 'GRE'.  So what's the problem here?

I searched the answer for a while, and found the suggested way to do this is the same as I did:

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935432/mysql-join-two-tables-on-like)

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing it correctly. you just have to use `TRIM()` to remove trailing whitespaces. Use it like

```
SELECT
    a.id as app_id,a.app_name,a.des,
    b.id as tag_id, b.name as tag_name
FROM aa_t_aaaa_app a
JOIN aa_t_aaaa_tag b
ON ((a.app_name LIKE CONCAT('%', TRIM(b.name) ,'%')) or (a.des Like CONCAT('%', TRIM(b.name) ,'%')))
order by a.id`
```

Comment: Thanx a lot!  You save my life.  ;)